# Como setar o atributo autofocus automaticamente em input HTML por JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso setar automaticamente o autofocus no input contido em um modal sempre que abri-lo.
Qual função JavaScript posso usar para isto?

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o e-mail" value="{{cliente.getEmail()}}" name="email" id="emailCliente" required>
```

Comment: como está abrindo esse modal? vai depender dele!

Comment: Clicando em um botão ele abre com o input. Preciso que esse input receba autofocus automaticamente.

Comment: Coloque todo exemplo na sua pergunta não temos como saber o que fez ai!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela classe que está no input `form-control` me parece que vc usa Bootstrap. Nesse casso na documentação eles indicam que use o evento `.on('shown.bs.modal', function () { }` para interagir com o modal, então no seu caso ficaria assim. Veja a documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').focus();
})
```

Veja o modelo funcionando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Abrir modal com input focado
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" value="sem foco" id="">
        <input type="text" value="input com autofocus" id="myInput">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myInput').focus();
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: @VictorMoraeslegal que deu certo ai! 

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso  adicionando  ao  evento  que abre o  modal

```
function abrirModal(){
    var element = document.getElementsByName("email")[0];
    element.focus();
}
```

Fiz  umas  correções no  codigo  e você  pode ver  ele funcionando aqui
https://jsfiddle.net/c25gvj9b/